# Reputation deducted for a downvote on another user's question

Tags: support

This is the link for the ticket for which I received downvote

[Ruby 1.9.3 nil? undefined local variable or method. Is nil? broken?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18892627/ruby-1-9-3-nil-undefined-local-variable-or-method-is-nil-broken/)

[image: downvote error]

The answer given by me has no downvote. How come the reputation has been deducted?

[image: no downvotes]

The question was asked by another user not me.

Comment: You may receive 1 upvote at same time receive one down vote..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer has a score of 0.

It had an upvote and then, later on, a downvote.

You do not currently have enough reputation for the [established user](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/established-user) privilege which allows you to see the upvote/downvote split.

> [image]

Comment: The user can however find all these recent events within his reputation history. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1553787/vamsi-krishna?tab=reputation

Answer (score 1):

You may receive 1 up vote after some time or same time receive one down vote

Comment: Same time doesn't matter here.

Comment: @hims056 Yes.. OK accepted.. Language problem..